# How to solve the E:Malformed entry 55 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component), problem

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu and so far I have this problem: I've tried to install skype and couldn't do it. Then the software "app" stop working and I get an error of Failed to load the package list, followed by details:

```
E:Malformed entry 55 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component),  
E:The list of sources could not be read.
```

I'm really rookie at this, but I've tried my best figuring out through older ask ubuntu questions of the "E:Malformed entry 54"  but that is not working.

Please help.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/896598/edit), select it, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: And what exactly did you do from the previous posts that did not work?

Comment: @muru do you know why the down vote on the question, and my accepted answer?

Comment: @heynnema on the question, see my comment. On your answer, I don't know, but I can add one more if you like.

Comment: @muru an up vote would make me feel so much better :-)

Comment: @heynnema goes for all of us.

Comment: @heynnema I don't know for sure the reason why anyone downvotes answers except for myself. As for myself, I would never downvote any of your answers because I know that you like to follow up on your answers. Instead if I read something in one of your answers that I didn't like I would post a comment about it and give you plenty of time to follow up on it.

Comment: @karel I really appreciate your answer! Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem...

In `terminal`...

```
cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list
```

observe the contents of line #55. That's where your error is. Normal lines start with `deb http://` or `deb-src http://` or `#`.

Backup the file...

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/source.list.backup
```

Now to edit out the problem...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and place a `#` at the front of the offending line to comment it out. Save the file and quit gedit.

**Update #1**

I've looked at your sources.list file, and I've found the problem. Unfortunately imgur.com makes a graphic image of the pasted text, so I can't just copy/paste the error lines here, so I'll have to use a graphic...

[image]

You'll see that the last 2 lines are duplicates of the first two lines, except that they're incomplete, and the 3rd line is specifically the one causing your problem.

Since you've been having a problem with gksudo, and with gedit, we'll give an example using the pico editor...

```
sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove the last two incomplete lines shown in my graphic, then save and quit.

**Pico note**: use arrow keys to move, **control-o, enter, control-x** to save and quit.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the quick response. Second: I reboot the computer and now the problem is in the 45th line (of 48), now, when I use the gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list command, the terminal says that the gksudo program isn't installed, when I try to install it goes:

N:  «50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist» del directorio «/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/», extention of file name invalid (I'm translating from spanish...)
E:Malformed entry 55 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component),  
E:The list of sources could not be read.

??

Comment: Then use **sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list**. If you have more problems, do a **cat /etc/apt/sources.list**, copy/paste that output into your original question, and I'll take a look. Start new comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: I did the sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list and nothing was weird with it, either way, I put a # save and exit and this showed up:

`(gedit:2448): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit:2448): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Establecer el atributo metadata::gedit-spell-enabled no está soportado

** (gedit:2448): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Establecer el atributo metadata::gedit-encoding no está soportado)`

Comment: Boy, you're having your share of problems, huh? Then do as I suggested, **cat /etc/apt/sources.list**, copy/paste it into your original question, and I'll take a look. When starting new comments directed to me, start them with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Let me know when I can take a look at your edit.

Comment: `@heynnema` 

Yup, I've been hours here trying to solve this, with the knowledge of a typewriter user. I've tried to edit the original question adding the copy/paste but the page says that I need 10 or more points of reputation to post more than 2 links...

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Then go to imgur.com, start a new post, paste in your output, and then let me know what the URL is, and I'll go take a look there.

Comment: `@heynnema`I'm sorry, this is the correct one:

http://imgur.com/a/tBtKx

Comment: `@heynnema` Thank you so much! It solved the problem! I upvoted you, but my reputation is less than 15 so it wont show on the counter but it is recorded. I think that I accepted your answer. Have a great day!

Comment: I'm glad it's working!